# Using RegEx to remove text between brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string

I am developing an iOS app and need to remove all text between brackets from a string, including the brackets. Example: "Look at this image [960x640]" should be "Look at this image"

My code works fine if there's only one set of brackets, but if there's multiple, it only removes the first set.

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithoutBrackets:(NSString *)input{
    NSString *expression = @"\\[[\\w]+\\]";
    while ([input rangeOfString:expression options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound){
        input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:expression withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Look at this image [960x640] and [somethingelse]"];
NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\\[[\\\w]+\\\]" options:0 error:&error];
[regularExpression replaceMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) withTemplate:@""];

NSLog(@"String %@", string);
```

Prints:Look at this image  and

Comment: Thank you. How would I modify this to remove parentheses rather than brackets?

Comment: @NickC, how can I remove the substring between ** or ^^?